# PHP linking - foo --> foo.php

Tags: apache-2.2

I am not sure if this belongs here or on Doctype, so I decided to post here.

My question is simple - Most the links on my site, if you were to copy the location right off the main page it would be something like www.example.com/dog/foo

and they return 404's . But if you were to type in www.example.com/dog/foo.php, the proper page would be displayed.

Is there anyway to make it so the .php is added automatically for every page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you implement some sort of URL Rewriting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get rid of .php suffix in url strings so they look pretty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062026/whats-the-best-way-to-get-rid-of-php-suffix-in-url-strings-so-they-look-pretty)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .htaccess file if you are using a apache server. But you don't even need a file that is actually called foo.php. See this example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule nice/link/name$ foo.php?param=value
```

This would point the link example.com/nice/link/name to the script foo.php in the root dir and even adding a parameter. That is used by many sites using the .htaccess file. For your needs you might use this rewrite  rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule dog/(.*)$ dog/$1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that you may be interested in, rather than rewriting the URL, is MultiViews, which will allow you to navigate to `example.com/dog/foo.php` as `example.com/dog/foo`. I personally enjoy MultiViews more as it allows you to have things such as `example.com/view/8-26-2010/stuff/you/posted` where `view` is the actual php file and `/8-26-2010/stuff/you/posted/` is a query passed to it. Anyways, to enable MultiViews put this in your `.htaccess`

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
```

Comment: Actually your second example with `example/view/8-26-2010/stuff/you/posted` is not entirely accurate. Yes, Apache will find the first file in the URI path that corresponds to the page presented the remaining path is sent as `PATH_INFO` rather than the query string. The `MultiViews` just enables it to pick up the file without the extension being provided.

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for in Apache is `MultiViews`. With this set in your `Options` either in a .htaccess file or the main Apache configuration file(s) it will tell Apache to find any files with extensions it understands and present it when a more complete filename is not given. This does mandate that the extension (in this case .php) be configured for the proper handler, but if giving the full filename (foo.php) works then that shouldn't be a problem.